# Blender animation will render images in solid

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

So basically lets say I have a cube and I have given him an emission shader from the node shaders, and when I render it in edit mode it glows as it should.

So the problem is when I click on animation after I've done an animation with this cube, blender goes through each frame and its showing me a rendered image of the cube with its emission as it should, however when its done the images for the animation are all like solid, unshaded like this:

[image]

Its actually supposed to be showing like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the OpenGL animation preview.

Comment: What button are you pressing to start the render?